# Using either GET or POST depending on submit button

Tags: html, forms

I have a web application for tagging data and viewing data by tag, so my UI is a list of checkboxes for each tag, a list of checkboxes for each data item, a "Tag" button, which adds the checked tags to the checked data, and a "Filter" button, which ignores the checked data and just displays only the data items with the given tag.

My problem is that the former operation (tagging data) is "obviously" a POST operation, whereas the latter operation (viewing data according to a tag) is "obviously" a GET operation. But the method attribute is attached to the form, not the submit button, so I have to choose one or other for both buttons.

I don't want to make two forms, since as far as I can tell this would force me to duplicate the entire tag list. Is there any way I can choose my method based on the choice of submit button?

A JavaScript solution is permissible, but one without would be preferred.

(I am going to post an answer to this question, but I don't particularly like it, so I would welcome alternatives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you could use the `formmethod` attribute in a submit button, as per HTML5. However, it is not recognized by IE, even in IE 9. The existence of the feature in HTML5 indirectly proves that previous versions of HTML lack a feature for this.

On the other hand, the POST method can be used even for simple viewing that does not cause any changes in the outside world, and in many situations it *has* to be used for technical reasons (e.g., too much data). So I think the method issue is not very relevant; just use POST.

Comment: I didn't know about the `formmethod` attribute, interesting! I suppose I could use formmethod for most browsers and one of the other solutions for IE. I think my main objection to using POST is that I would like people to be able to link each other certain tag combinations, and that Firefox insists on a confirm dialog every time I refresh the page, which is a nuisance, but I realise neither of these are critical (and indeed for the moment I am just using POST).

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly go with a javascript solution, in the `onsubmit` of the form fire a method which **a)** checks the submit button that was pressed and **b)** based on this changes the method of the form.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use POST, and then have the server give a 303 See Other header to change it into a GET request. This involves making two requests to serve the purpose of one, which is unfortunate, but at least means that the URL will change so people can link to a specific tag selection.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `javascript` solution, proposed by Jon Taylor, the problem is not if your form's method is GET or POST, but how do you filter/validate/sanitize user input. If your concern is related to the fact, that the user can manipulate the form's method, then you should implement solution to that matter on server side.

Comment: This is not a security measure, it is a convenience measure. I want GET because I want the URL to reflect which tags are being displayed, I want POST because I want to change content with the request (so features like Firefox's confirming before you refresh are useful). So I don't think that input sanitization is an issue.